# Is it possible to change to documentclass 'scrbook' in bookdown?

Tags: r, pandoc, bookdown

I want to change the documentclass to 'scrbook'. In the index.Rmd file of minimal bookdown example I changed the line `documentclass: book` to `documentclass: scrbook` but this didn't work. I got the following error message:

```
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 19 Jan. 2017, version: 4.52c.
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Non-existent destination files:
      'test-bookdown.pdf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running '/Library/TeX/texbin/xelatex  -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -recorder  "test-bookdown.tex"'
------------
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
=== TeX engine is 'XeTeX'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Latexmk: Log file says no output from latex
Latexmk: For rule 'pdflatex', no output was made
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'test-bookdown.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
! LaTeX Error: Command \subtitle already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

Error: Failed to compile test-bookdown.tex. See test-bookdown.log for more info.
Please delete test-bookdown.Rmd after you finish debugging the error.
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Is there a way to change to other document classes besides those supported by [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex) (article, report, book, memoir)?

I used for the compilation the command `rmarkdown::render_site(output_format = 'bookdown::pdf_book', encoding = 'UTF-8')` as provided by the `Build Book` tab.

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.2       backports_1.1.1      bookdown_0.5.4       magrittr_1.5         rprojroot_1.2       
 [6] htmltools_0.3.6      tools_3.4.2          yaml_2.1.14          Rcpp_0.12.13         stringi_1.1.5       
[11] rmarkdown_1.6.0.9004 knitr_1.17           stringr_1.2.0        digest_0.6.12        evaluate_0.10.1  

> rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘1.19.2.1’
> system('pdflatex --version')
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.29; using libpng 1.6.29
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `scrbook` as an example in the **bookdown** book in [Section 4.2](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/theming.html). Had you searched for `scrbook` using the search button, you would have discovered it. I'm not going to copy the full example here, but the key is `template: null`, and that is because **rmarkdown**'s default Pandoc LaTeX template does not work with `scrbook`, and Pandoc's LaTeX template does. You can certainly provide your own Pandoc LaTeX template.